# Mod Rewrite issue

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a huge .htaccess file, with a lot of rewrites.
I want to make a modification, that will affect every rewrite.

Let's say I have

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ request.php?id=$3&txt=$2&cat=$1`

If I will have `www.mysite.com/magic/info-212.html?condition=1` I will want to add to `request.php` that `condition=1`, but I can have anything after `?` (eg: `add=magic`, `kill=php`)

I don't want to modify all the rewrites for something that may be or not be added.

Comment: just out of curiosity .. why down-voted after 3 years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the `QSA` (query string append) flag is what your looking for.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ request.php?id=$3&txt=$2&cat=$1 [QSA]
```

This would rewrite `www.mysite.com/magic/info-212.html?condition=1` to `www.mysite.com/request.php?id=212&txt=info&cat=magic&condition=1`.